# How do I make 'bookmarks' in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

[This.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7e3mG.png)

I know that calling it a bookmark is probably wrong, but I don't know any better names.

Comment: Looks like a `ttk.Notebook` widget (in which case they're _child pane tabs_). Here's a little [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20190508203309id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Notebook.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you want is referred to as a "Notebook" in tkinter.

The link below has information on how to do this:

https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/tkinter.Notebook